# Easiest way to use bundle resources for testing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctest

Its convenient to use bundle resources for testing, for example to provide the expected outcome for a test.

For the old logic-style tests, I would use the main bundle for this, however for application style tests the main bundle is the app itself. I don't want to put test resources in the main bundle.

Eg, the following code is not working if the test resource only belongs to the test target:

```
//Load a resource from the main bundle
NSString* xml = [[JBBundleResource withName:@"signUpResponse.xml"] asString];
```

. . . is there a specific bundle for the tests? How can I get a handle to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use:

```
NSBundle *testBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[YourTestClass class]];
```

or in Swift 3:

```
let testBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
```

in tests code. Everything you add in 'Copy Bundle Resources' in 'Build Phases' for your Tests target in XCode will be available in this bundle.

Comment: Ah yes - that was easy!. In fact now I recall doing this some time back. For a while I stopped using "application" style tests, as they were tricky to get working from the cmd-line, meaning headache to set up CI builds. . . that all seems fixed now, so its back to using them again.

Comment: Swift3: `let testBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))`